# Using .loc with a column of values

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have a slice of a column within a dataframe `df` where I want to replace float values with other float values. Only the values to replace are from another dataframe, `newdf.

I've tried using

`df.loc[row index condition, [column to replace vals]] = newdf[column]`

but for some reason the resulting values are all `NaN`. Why is this so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value from `newdf` need to align with the `index` of `df`. If `newdf` has the exact number of values you want to insert, you can try using [`.values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html):

```
df.loc[row index condition, [column to replace vals]] = newdf[column].values
```

Comment: .values was the trick! The slice is the exact same number of rows, but I could no longer merge on indices. Perfect, thank you!